# How to avoid the "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls" message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, internet-explorer

I have some HTML pages that need to be run from a local DVD. The HTML pages use jQuery and knockout.js.

They run fine on Firefox, Safari, Chrome but from IE9, for every page, I get an `Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls` message. The pages need to be executed from the local DVD so that I cannot be sure that users change the security level of their browser. Is there a way to avoid the message from HTML pages/script?

Comment: just curious are your scripts up or down in path from the HTML page loading them? ../scipts/ or ./scripts/ if they are up, try adding them  in the same root

Comment: You could also try making the scripts inline. if FlavorScape's suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: They are inside a js directory, so in <script src="js/script.js"> . I can try to put them in the same dir

Comment: @FlavorScape i really thank you, if i move the scripts in ../ or ../js/ dir it runs ! Don't' know why .... Anyway if you put your comment as answer, i will surely mark that as accepted !

Comment: cool! I made it and answer, please accept (and upvote if it was useful) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moves scripts down-path from your HTML.  ../scipts/ will not work.  {yourhtmlpageroot}/scripts/

if they are upstream from the DOM page, security violations occur because the browser thinks the page is trying to access scripts somewhere else on your machine since it is up-stream of the document path.